# Creating flat buttons for login, Facebook and signup in PFLogInViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform

My app follows more of a flat design and I'd love to make the buttons for login, signup and Facebook more flat on the PFLogInViewController.

I'd like to avoid creating an image for a button (that's just a software purist in me).  Is there a way to make the buttons flat?  Currently the buttons have a gradient on them.

Also the text seems to be doubled up somehow.  I am dropping the shadow, but something is still there.

```
[self.logInView.signUpLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
layer = self.logInView.signUpLabel.layer;
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download the new SDK which is designed for iPhone 6 and also has a flat UI redesign.

http://blog.parse.com/2014/11/06/introducing-the-new-parseui-for-ios/

Comment: Thanks!  After I actually figured out a good way to do it they released an update :) explains why they didn't promote my blog post :)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a good way to solve this problem and of course Parse has updated their SDK as well.  For those of you who are looking to customize the buttons on the old framework or another SDK check this out:

http://www.mikebz.com/2014/11/give-parsecom-dialogs-modern-look.html